# Unrecognized selector error from calling a function on a timer

Tags: ios, swift

New to Objective C and trying to store past gps data using a timer. My code is as follows ('data' is declared earlier in the class as an instance of a struct with the multiple arrays you see):

```
var synchronizer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: timerClass.self, selector: #selector(cycle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
@objc func cycle()
{
    data.timeArray.insert(Date.init(), at: 0)
    if (data.timeArray.count > 30) {
        data.timeArray = data.timeArray.dropLast(data.timeArray.count - 30)
    }
    loc.requestLocation()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var ts = "Time: ["
    for time in data.timeArray {
        ts.append(" " + dateFormatter.string(from: time) + ",")
    }
    ts.append("]")
    timeString.text = ts
    var ss = "Speed: ["
    for loc in data.speedArray {
        ss.append(" " + String(format:"%.0f",loc.speed*2.237) + ",")
    }
    ss.append("]")
    timeString.text = ss
}
```

As soon as the timer actually *runs* I get this error:
`[projectName.timerClass cycle]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1032fba38`

I have to assume that the issue is with my declaration of 'synchronizer', but I can't find any differing instructions for Objective C.

Comment: It's a Swift code, not Objective-C

Comment: If you are getting data from core location you probably don't even need a timer. If you `startUpdatingLocation` you will get approximately 1hz location updates via the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the code takes place in the scope of a class named `timerClass`, so surrounding looks something like this:

```swift
class timerClass {

    var synchronizer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: timerClass.self, selector: #selector(cycle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    ...
}
```

Since you try to access `self` from the context of default property value, the compiler apparently suggested to switch to `timerClass.self`, however that is not what you want to access here, because it refers to the class, not its instance.

As long as you need to refer to `self`, you should initialise your property lazily:

```
lazy var synchronizer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(cycle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Or inside of a constructor:

```
var synchronizer: Timer

init() {
    synchronizer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(cycle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: The lazy instantiation worked.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to send timer event to a class, rather than to an instance. The target needs to be an instance of `timerClass` (which I hope is spelled "TimerClass" with a leading capital as classes should be).